# SM-P600, lte, wifi, or 3g?

Tags: lineageos, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I'm having a problem where every time I boot a rom on an SM-P600, I get a boot halt. I would like to know how to verify which version I have. LineageOS has a build for,

- [n1awifi](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/n1awifi/)
- [lt03lte](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/lt03lte)

Answer (score 1):

SM-P600 is the WiFi variant. From the device codenames you can easily see that `n1awifi` is for the WiFi variant (SM-P600) and `lt03lte` is for the LTE variant (SM-P605, SM-P607T).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers should be correct, per @Andy Yan's answer, but you can validate that that by checking `/proc/cpuinfo` via `adb shell`,

From TWRP, I can `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and I get

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 1590.88

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : UNIVERSAL5420
Revision    : 0005
Serial      : b8c9c00b4300448b
```

UNIVERSAL5420 is the hardware name for the Exynos 5420 which is in the SM-P600 model, but that doesn't matter anyway so long as the architecture hardware is the same.

Comment: Additionally, the 3G variant (SM-P601) also has a E5420, though you know that could be easily told apart by a presence of a SIM slot. The LTE variants have SD800.